# cloudfoundry mysql updates don't work

Tags: mysql, grails, cloud-foundry

I have a grails app deployed on cloudfoundry with mysql db. The updates into the tables are flaky - when  I change values it works sometimes and it doesn't work most of the times. There are no errors. It looks as if updates are going into a different db. I looked up vmc services and there is only one db associated with the application.

Since they work sometimes, it looks like a cloudfoundry problem. Has anyone seen this? Is there a special config for updates to work consistently ? Any information is appreciated.

Comment: It is unlikely a cloudfoundry problem.  Have you checked the DataSource? http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/services/mysql/grails-mysql.html

Comment: Can you show some pieces of code where you store the data? Are you sure the data is already flushed when you are saving it?

Comment: I think you are right may not be cloudfoundry problem. I have second level cache and query cache enabled. However, this is not problem on local deployments, started seeing them only on cloud deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tunneling via vmc command to check the db bound to your app and see if the desired record is there. Would probably some app issue if you find it missing.

Comment: I could never figure out why updates are taking long to show up in my cloudfoundry deployments. The update takes into effect sometimes immediately and it doesn't sometimes - strangely. I do tunnel to the db instance and query to see, no updates are seen until few minutes. No sql update failures are seen. So it looks like a synchronization issue. I moved onto a different cloud vendor.